# Esp8266-server comminication

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webserver

Esp8266 is working with AT+Commands. So i'm trying to create a very simple server to communicate with.
My first question is, can i create a database as a web server? And esp8266 to communicate directly to my database with queries? Lets say that i will use mySql.
Second question if i need to communicate first with a web server using c# how can i create local server in my pc which can receive and send requests?

Here is an example with what i'm sending from esp8266

```
AT+CIPSEND=4,46\r\n
AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n
AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","192.168.0.214",5000\r\n
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: http://localhost:5000/\r\n
AT+CIPCLOSE=4\r\n
```

I dont know how to start with this. I'm asking in forum cause i 'm trying to find an easy way to do this.

Also i found this example. But how i will combine it for sending request and answering from client?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting server...");
        _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5000/"); // add prefix "http://localhost:5000/"
        _httpListener.Start(); // start server (Run application as Administrator!)
        Console.WriteLine("Server started.");
        Thread _responseThread = new Thread(ResponseThread);
        _responseThread.Start(); // start the response thread
    }
    static void ResponseThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            HttpListenerContext context = _httpListener.GetContext(); // get a context
            // Now, you'll find the request URL in context.Request.Url
            byte[] _responseArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head><title>Localhost server -- port 5000</title></head>" + 
                "<body>Welcome to the <strong>Localhost server</strong> -- <em>port 5000!</em></body></html>"); // get the bytes to response
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(_responseArray, 0, _responseArray.Length); // write bytes to the output stream
            context.Response.KeepAlive = false; // set the KeepAlive bool to false
            context.Response.Close(); // close the connection
            Console.WriteLine("Respone given to a request.");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Talking directly to MySQL is going to be hard, I think. The easist way will probably be to program the ESP in C and porting a MySQL client library to the ESP. I assume you're using LUA now on the ESP? Then the easiest way is probably to create a server that exposes a REST API and talks to MySQL for you. That's fairly simple to do in C# and your ESP code will look a lot like your example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Esp is speaking with at commands and controller is speaking with c using uart method. The thing is that i dont know how to start. Is there any easy tutorial. How will i create such an application? Also if i will create it in c#, in future can i upload my c# application on server to making the same work? or its better starting learning php or html for this job?

Comment: Ah, OK. If you're talking to the ESP over the serial connection, then I would start exploring programming the ESP. If it has the NodeMCU firmware installed (I think most ESPs come with this pre-installed), you can find some examples here: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware

Comment: I think the most easy is to create an api query server(Web api) am i right?

Comment: Yes, I agree. If you go with dotnet core 2.1, you can use the WebApi template as a starting point. Then you basically just need to add the database access.

Comment: Is it the same if i will create an http server in c#? Can i read-response queries there?